# P4Python issue: p4run("files", 'path') returns - no such file(s) although returns single item dict for "dirs"

Tags: python, synchronization, structure, p4python, depot

I'm trying to read depot structure without syncing and got stuck on files listing.

Why this returns single-item dict:

```
p4.run("dirs", '//folder1/Trunk/projects')
```

but this:

```
p4.run("files", '//folder1/Trunk/projects')
```

Error:

> [Warning]: '//folder1/Trunk/projects - no such file(s).'

Why is that?

There are other folders in that location and I would like to access some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Correct command:
p4.run("files", '//folder1/Trunk/projects/...')